# Remove a Reference from the Release configuration without removing it from the Debug Configuration

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

How can I add a `Reference` (in the References folder) to the **Debug** Configuration without adding it to the **Release** Configuration?

Is there a way to do this in Xamarin Studio using the GUI? There does not seem to be any options available in the **Properties** contextual menu.

Answer (score 0):

As of Xamarin Studio 6, there is no way to do that from the IDE.
You need to manually edit the Xamarin Project in that Solution `.csproj` using a text editor, such as **Terminal**.

Add `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'` to the `Reference` or `ProjectReference`.

---

Example:

- `<Reference Include="xxx.dll" />`
  *becomes*
- `<Reference Include="xxx..dll" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"/>`

Comment: Yeah there's not a great way to do this other than a custom `MSBuild` conditional as defined in your answer. I've seen people go as far as creating custom `.bat/.sh` scripts to get a project ready for Debug/Release with references.